# How to access URL queries that have hyphen in them vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I am trying to display a `v-alert` conditionally based on whether the `payment-successful` query parameter is `true` or `false`.

Here's what I tried:

```html
<v-alert v-if="$route.query.payment-successful == true" type="success" dismissible>
  I'm an alert
</v-alert>
```

But it does not seem to work since the alert is not being displayed when I set the query param. I also tried putting the `$route.query.payment-successful` between quotes but it did not work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out to use `[]` squared brackets accessor :

```html
<v-alert v-if="$route.query['payment-successful'] == true"></v-alert>
```